# JavaScript: How to run AJAX queries in specific order, waiting for certain calls to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The code is below and so are the problems I am facing. First is what I would like to happen:

**THIS WOULD BE THE IDEAL OUTCOME**

Run this one request

```
/cc/AjaxController/justTheSplit/normal
```

**After this one request has completed**, run the following

```
/cc/AjaxController/workCsv/0/normal
...
/cc/AjaxController/workCsv/100/normal
```

**After all 101 have run**, run the following

```
/cc/AjaxController/sortHours/0/normal
...
/cc/AjaxController/sortHours/100/normal
```

**After all 101 have run**, run the following

```
/cc/AjaxController/workFilters/0/normal
...
/cc/AjaxController/workFilters/100/normal
```

**After all 101 have run**, go do the same but for abnormal and then for wizard

**Once all have run**, then run one last Ajax request

**CODE**

```
function processData() {
    const types = {1:"normal", 2:"abnormal", 3:"wizard"};
    for (let [key, ty] of Object.entries(types)) {
        var days = 101;
        var i;
        var x = -1;
        var y = -1;
        var z = -1;

        $.get('/cc/AjaxController/justTheSplit/'+ty, function(data, status) {
            for (i=0;i<days;i++) {
                $('.days-progress-'+ty).show();
                $.get('/cc/AjaxController/workCsv/'+i+'/'+ty, function(data, status) {
                    $('.days-progress-'+ty).find('.progress-bar').css('width', i+'%');
                    x++;
                    $.get('/cc/AjaxController/sortHours/'+x+'/'+ty, function(data, status) {
                        y++;
                        $('.hours-progress-'+ty).find('.progress-bar').css('width', (y+1)+'%');
                        $.get('/cc/AjaxController/workFilters/'+y+'/'+ty, function(data, status) {
                            z++;
                            $('.filters-progress-'+ty).find('.progress-bar').css('width', (z+1)+'%');
                            if (z===100 && y===100 && z===100 && ty==='rocu') {
                                $.get('/cc/AjaxController/cleanData', function(data, status) {
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problems I am having are:

- The values of x,y and z never get reset so they go up to 303
- The Ajax requests don't seem to wait for the previous ones to complete before going onto next batch

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code within an `async` function (or expand the `await`s with `then` chain)

```
const calls = ['normal', 'abnormal', 'wizard']
const range = Array.from({length:101},(v,k)=>k) // build number array

let build = (url) => calls.flatMap( x => range.map(y => $.get(url + y +'/' + x))) // generates the 303 ajax requests

let init = calls.map(x => $.get('/cc/AjaxController/justTheSplit/' + x)) // generate initial requests
await $.when(...init) // wait all to finish

let step1 = build('/cc/AjaxController/workCsv/')
await $.when(...step1)

let step2 = build('/cc/AjaxController/sortHours/')
await $.when(...step2)

let step3 = build('/cc/AjaxController/workFilters/')
await $.when(...step3)
```

Beware: all 303 requests of each step will run in parallel, as scheduled by the browser and accepted by the server. But the next step is only built and started when the previous one is completed. Further steps can easily be added using this approach. Of course, you should add `try-catch` around the code.

Progress-bar makes little sense here. Anyway, you can attach `done` handler to each individual request in the `build` function that does some visual feedback by counting the completed requests - that would not change the rest of the code. As each step is awaited, you can add progess feedback between steps also.